# Include Variables in PHP mail command

Tags: php, email, header

I'm sure I'm wrong about something basic, but can not find where the error is. I will appreciate your help.

I have a php page with a single 4 fields contact form.

I need send the name and email as variable, so i can see it properly when email is received.

**IT WORKS - BUT DONT SEND NAME AND EMAIL AS VARIABLE:**

All messages arrives as `"no-reply@luchodomain.com"` and doesnt look professional (and can't do reply from my outlook)

```
if ($_POST) {

            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            $to = "lucho@hotmail.com";
            $subject = "Website CONTACT";

            $headers = "From: no-reply@luchodomain.com" . "\r\n" ; 
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

            $message = "<html><body>";
            $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Subject:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['subject']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Message:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['message']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "</table>";
            $message .= "</body></html>";

            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
            }
```

**IT DOENST WORKS (but have the format and variables as i need)**

I would like receive the messages like is normal Name, so i can do a quick reply. -This code don't send email, doesn't work-

```
if ($_POST) {

            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];

            $to = "lucho@hotmail.com";
            $subject = "Website CONTACT";

            $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


            $message = "<html><body>";
            $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Subject:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['subject']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Message:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['message']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "</table>";
            $message .= "</body></html>";

            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
            }
```

I will appreciate your help with this "headers" issue!

Thank you.

Comment: Are you certain the email isn't being sent? This method, though fun, often causes issues with spam filters. If you have one, it might realize that the server you are sending this from isn't allowed to send email for that domain of the person that entered the information. If you just print the headers, what do they look like? Does your host require the -f flag for the php mail function?

Comment: Please provide the HTML form code, not the PHP code which you included twice

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are receiving data in your post array. Make sure your form action. You have declared $message variable to blank after assigning the post value in it before. That's not a good trick enough. Please check updated code and let me know.

```
if ($_POST) {

            $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
            $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
            $subject = strip_tags($_POST['subject']);
            $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

            $to = "lucho@hotmail.com";
            $subject = "Website CONTACT";

            $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


            //$message = "";
            //$message .= '';
            $message .= "\r\nName: " . $name . "";
            $message .= "Email: " . $email . "\r\n";
            $message .= "Subject: " . $subject . "\r\n";
            $message .= "Message: " . $message . "";
            //$message .= "";
            //$message .= "";

               mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
            }
```

Comment: Vin000, thanks for reply. Im receiving data, Form action is ok. For some reason the $message field appears empty, maybe because im using HTML elements (table) and this window can't display it. I'll try update my question with all the fields and html tags.

Comment: Code Edited, could help!

Answer (score 0):

`$to = 'pawanvikasitha2001@gmail.com, aravindasamapath87@gmail.com'; $subject = 'NEW ORDER HAS PLACED'; $message = "$name"; mail ($to,$subject,$message);`

When you use the double quotes, You can simply add variables to it. Look at the $message